# Ecommerce template for sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, e-commerce

Are there any good commercial e-commerce site templates (or site definitions?) for sharepoint?

I noticed a lot of strong opinions (good and bad) about sharepoint on this site, is this a good direction to take?

Answer (score 0):

Having been involved a few projects involving public facing sites built on SharePoint, I'd highly advise against building something as customization-heavy as an e-commerce site on it.

You'll end up spending more time on attempting to force the platform onto the requirements than actually doing any meaningful development.

In addition, the platform itself has a relatively sheltered development community consisting of mainly 3rd party vendors who tend to charge an arm and a leg for half baked solutions, so you won't be able to tap into much outside of that. (aside from the previously mentioned painful development process)